# yii2 findAll not working passing in parameter from variable

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii2

I am trying to get the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `book_category_tree` WHERE `id` IN (8, 9, 10, 15)
```

According the following yii2 documentation:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#findAll%28%29-detail

If i use:

```
$rows = BookCategoryTree::findAll([8,9,10,15]);
```

It works perfect but when ever I try to use a variable with the values yii2 doesn't recognize the values:

```
$myValues = '8,9,10,15';
$rows = BookCategoryTree::findAll([$myValues]);
```

and generates the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `book_category_tree` WHERE `id`='8,9,10,15'
```

I am getting crazy to avoid this I also tried:

```
$rows = BookCategoryTree::find()->where(['in','id',[$myValues]])->all();
```

But I have no luck.

Any ideas welcome,

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use  where condition with operator notation  like this

```
 $rows = BookCategoryTree::find()->where( ['in', 'id', [8,9,10,15]])->all();
```

or

```
 $myValues = [8,9,10,15];
 $rows = BookCategoryTree::find()->where(['in','id',$myValues])->all();
```

if you have value in string you can use explode for build an array

```
 $myValues =explode(',', $string_values);
```

Comment: Thaks for your answer but using this code you get: SELECT * FROM `book_category_tree` WHERE `id`=NULL

Comment: for both the query  ?  . show all the code  .. could be you are using a createCommand ..

Comment: I have sligthly updated the answer .. (the array assigment)

Comment: This works but i can't use it because I have the values in a string variable:  $string_values = "8, 9, 10, 15";
        $myValues = [$string_values];
        $rows = BookCategoryTree::find()->where(['in','id',$myValues])->all(); and then i have the same problem

Comment: @open-ecommerce.org   .. answer updated for string .. too  .. (could be you must remove the last element of the array)

Comment: can you edit your answer with the correct explode, $myValues = explode(',', $string_values); It works perfect thanks

Comment: @open-ecommerce.org   . answer  updated .. (missing  , added )